# CellValuePropertyFactory in TableColumn cannot be applied

Tags: java, javafx

So i'm trying to populate a TableView, but the problem is that I can't set the CellValueFactoryProperty, it says it cannot be applied, I've tried to look it up but i'm probably messing up in some point, because I don't seem to find the answer, or even the same error.

PD: I'm using JPA and Hibernate, don't think that matters tho.

This is the problem:

```
private void fillTable() {

colID.cellValueFactoryProperty(new PropertyValueFactory<Alumnos, Integer> 
("ID"));

}
```

---

Here are my columns:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Alumnos, Integer> colID;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Alumnos, String> colNombre;
```

---

And this is basically my Alumnos class:

```
@Entity
public class Alumnos {
    private int aluId;
    private String aluNom;
```

I only expect to be able to set the CellValueFactoryProperty right.

Comment: You're trying to pass the value to the property getter method. This method does not take parameters though. Either do `colID.cellValueFactoryProperty().set(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));` or better `colID.setCellValueFactoryProperty(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));`

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot, such a small problem had me stuck for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the first comment, I'll post it here to help fellow coders.

You're trying to pass the value to the property getter method. This method does not take parameters though. Either do `colID.cellValueFactoryProperty().set(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));` or better `colID.setCellValueFactoryProperty(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));`

So just substitute

```
colID.cellValueFactoryProperty(new PropertyValueFactory<Alumnos, Integer>("ID"));
```

to:

```
colID.setCellValueFactoryProperty(new PropertyValueFactory<Alumnos, Integer>("ID"));
```

Credits to @fabian.
Thank you.